# What is localization practices?

Tags: localization

I am applying for a job and in the description, it says "The ideal candidate for this position is a team player, possesses excellent communication skills, and demonstrates a strong understanding of software development and localization practices." I am confused by the term localization practices. To my understanding, it means that to make the software easy to be understood/used by people from another culture. If this is the case, how can I be prepared for this job?
Here is the link to the post: https://www.glassdoor.ca/job-listing/sap-ixp-intern-developer-translation-tools-sap-JV_IC2278756_KO0,42_KE43,46.htm?jl=2616521940&ctt=1516176176268

Comment: To localize software, you need to consider i18n (the preparation of your code for later l10n (localization)) from the beginning. This is a lot of work to “shove in later”. That’s *probably* what that refers to. But you’ll only really know if you go and ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localization is the process of adapting a product or  content to a specific locale or market. Creating  “global-ready” software ensures that key functional features—interface, metric units, graphics, and navigation, for example—were designed specifically for the target market, regardless of language, culture, or location.

In short user satisfaction...

create the application or what ever it is as simple as possible its only that means..

[this will help you](http://content.lionbridge.com/5-best-practices-for-software-localization-infographic/)